# Pub/Sub Criteria Issue

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to create a filtering mechanism on the client side. I've published only collections that have not been removed; `{ removed: false }`. Then on the client I sometimes want to add a second criteria `{tag: 'Sports'}`. The code I have does not work, unfortunately. I assumed my arguments for the subscribe would extend the criteria of the publish. Maybe I am wrong?

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
    return Posts.find({ removed: false });
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts', { tag: 'Sports' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First solution

Server:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function(query) {
    // if passed query is NULL, then query = {}
    query = query || {};
    // we need to be sure that always we filter by  {removed : false}
    query.removed = false;
    return Posts.find(query);
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts',{tag:'Sports'});
```

### Second solution

Your publish function is fine, second filtering you are doing on client side.

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts');
```

The second criteria can be used inside Template helper:

```
Template.template_name.posts = function(){
   return Posts.find({tag:'Sports'});
}
```

You use it like that:

```
<template name="posts">
 {{ posts }}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks @parhelium! The first solution works great! Although, could you explain to me why this works?

Comment: If you would like to understand how publish / subscribe design pattern in meteor works then I recommend to read book [Discover Meteor](http://www.discovermeteor.com/).

Comment: I had tried something similar to your solution earlier, which I had gotten from Discover Meteor, but it didn't work correctly. I'm guessing I just overlooked something. I'm extremely tired at this point, I need sleep! Thanks again.