# What is the correct way to selectively publish in Meteor based on information in the database?

Tags: meteor

For instance, when your permissions are group-based, and your user document has a list of groups that the user belongs to. I'm publishing docs in an Items collection, and you should only be able to view items with a `groupOwner` field matching a group you belong to.

It would be nice if you could autorun inside a publish, but I doubt you can:

```
Meteor.publish 'screened-items', ->
  Deps.autorun ->
    user = Users.findOne @userId
    return Items.find {groupOwner: {$in: user.groups}}
```

If you can't, this is the best I can come up with, but it's going to be slow and memory-intensive. Is this the only way to do it?

```
Meteor.publish 'screened-items', ->
  user = Users.findOne @userId

  # (hope that the db doesn't change between this line and the observeChanges)
  saved_items = Items.find({groupOwner: {$in: user.groups}}).fetch()
  # call @added on each item

  handle = Users.findOne(@userId).observeChanges {
    changed: (_, fields) =>
      if fields.groups
        new_items = Items.find({groupOwner: {$in: fields.groups}}).fetch()
        # compare new_items to saved_items, and call @added() or @removed() for each difference
  }

  @ready()
  @.onStop ->
    handle.stop()
```

Comment: Why would the first one not work? Have you tried it?

Comment: I haven't. I will if someone doesn't have a quick answer. In order for autorun to work, wouldn't Meteor need to put its use of what I return in their own autorun, treating what I return as a reactive data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this two ways:

1. Use the `publish-with-relations` package, for example:

   ```
   Meteor.publish 'screend-items', ->
     # select the current user
     Meteor.publishWithRelations
       handle: this
       collection: Meteor.users
       filter:
         _id: @userId
       options:
         fields:
           groups: 1
       mappings: [
         key: 'groupOwner'  # and map to the `groupOwner` field on Items
         collection: Items
       ]
   ```
2. Denormalize the relationship, providing a succinct list of users to use for publishing

   ```
   Items._ensureIndex(userIds: 1) # best to index this field
   # basic publications
   Meteor.publish 'screend-items', ->
     # don't expose `userIds` to the client
     return Items.find({userIds: @userId}, {fields: userIds: false})
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the published docs to change when the userId changes, that is the default behaviour.

> However, if the logged-in user changes, the publish function is rerun with the new value. - from [docs.meteor.com](http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_userId).

Deps.autorun() only works on the client while Meteor.publish() only works on the server.  So you can not autorun inside of publish.

If you are okay to let the client see the 'groups' they're in, the code is a bit simpler because you can start and stop the subscription when the groups change.  Like this:

```
//on client 
Deps.autorun( function() {
  Meteor.subscribe( 'items', Meteor.user().groups );
});

//on server
Meteor.publish( 'items', function( groups ){
  var self = this;
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne( {_id: self.userId});

  if ( ! (user && user.groups === groups) )
    return;

  return Items.find({groupOwner: {$in: groups}});
});
```

Otherwise you would need use two observers inside the publish function - one to watch user for changes to groups and another to manage publishing items that are in the group.  See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688718/meteor-one-to-many-relationship-add-field-only-to-client-side-collection-in-p/21059621#21059621) of doing a join of collections that way.

Comment: I don't trust the client to tell the server which group it is in.

Two observers sounds better than my second solution.

Comment: You don't have to trust the user.  The publish example I provided checks that the user provided info is exactly equal to what comes from the db.  Having the user provide it is just a way to trigger the rerun of the publish.